# ListView React native cloneWithRows is not getting proper data

Tags: javascript, react-native, lambda, arrow-functions

I am trying to pass the data from one screen to another and I have data in

this.props.data which has something like this ["12121","434536"], I am trying to do the following
trying to add that data to list via `this.ds.cloneWithRows([values])`,

but I am getting output like below:

`["12121","434536"]` in one row, its not adding the elements one after another.

```
let values= [];
      values =this.props.data;
      alert(values)
     this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {

      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows([values]),


<ListView
        style={{width: '100%'}}
          renderHeader={() => <Text style={styles.text}>adding Started</Text>}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <View style={{borderWidth:1, borderColor: '#232C46',borderRadius: 4}}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, {backgroundColor: '#192034'}]}>{rowData}</Text>
            </View>
          }
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, with the first answer, it's a syntax error ("values" is already in the correct form, no need to put it in an array).

Also, just FYI, ListView is a deprecated component and you may want to convert this into a FlatList for fewer bugs, better performance / memory usage, and I think a more intuitive API.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Comment: I guess the data in values is in string format, is there any way to change it to array ? eg: var s= "["234234"]" ; s.toArray();

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already an array. You don't need the extra `[]`

Change it like below;

```
this.ds.cloneWithRows(values)
```

Comment: it is not working then I checked the length of data to check how many elemets i have , I guess values is in string format .

Comment: basically i need to convert "["1231","1231"]" to javascript array , is there any way to so this ?

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni try with `JSON.parse(values)`